# Changing facet labels with spplot

Tags: r

I am trying to create a side-by-side of two spatial surfaces (each have the same grid locations). Following the example provided [here](https://fukamilab.github.io/BIO202/08-A-mapping.html), I was able to produce the plot below on a toy example. However, I can't seem to figure out how to change the facet labels such that they contain two words (e.g., "Predicted Surface"). I would also like the color scale to be continuous and on the right hand side. Any help would be much appreciated as well as other advice in making my plot prettier! (I don't have to use spplot, it just seemed easiest to me).

```
library(fields)
set.seed(123)
n=5000
print(n)
gridLocation<-cbind(runif(n,min = 0,max = 5),runif(n,min = 0,max = 5))
distMat<-as.matrix(rdist(gridLocation)) # Distance matrix
expCov<-function(distMat,phi){
  exp(-distMat/phi)
}
CovMat <- expCov(distMat,phi=1)
W1 <- as.numeric(t(chol(CovMat))%*%rnorm(n))
W2 <- W1+rnorm(n)

data <- data.frame(x=gridLocation[,1],y=gridLocation[,2], W1=W1, W2=W2)
coordinates(data) <- c("x", "y") # tells r to use x and y collumns as the lat/long 
spplot(data, c("W1","W2")) # easy way to plot side by side maps
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't reproducible (where does `rdist` come from?) but its not necessary, a simple example can be constructed much more easily:

```
> data = data.frame(x=runif(100), y=runif(100), W1=runif(100), W2=runif(100))
> coordinates(data) = ~x+y
```

Now I can plot it with W1 and W2 labels:

```
> spplot(data, names(data)) # easy way to plot side by side ma
```

There's no reason why you can't give column names two-word values, its perfectly valid R, although it elicits a warning:

```
> names(data)[1] = "First Item"
Warning message:
In checkNames(value) :
  attempt to set invalid names: this may lead to problems later on. See ?make.names
```

But you can still get at the data by name:

```
> head(data[["First Item"]])
[1] 0.26261320 0.03832961 0.30458142 0.67045738 0.82739282 0.70987561
```

Or even using $-extraction if you protect the name in backticks:

```
> head(data$`First Item`)
[1] 0.26261320 0.03832961 0.30458142 0.67045738 0.82739282 0.70987561
```

But `spplot` doesn't like it one little bit:

```
> spplot(data, names(data)) # easy way to plot side by side ma
Error in create.z(as(obj, "data.frame"), zcol) : 
  no support for variable of this type
```

Oh well. So then I read the documentation for `spplot` and discovered the `names.attr` parameter:

```
spplot(data, names(data), names.attr=c("First Thing","Second thing"))
```

[image]

Moral of the story: I should read the documentation first.

Note the `sp` package and friends are retiring soon, so you should really look into the `sf` package and its friends for work from now on. Any tutorials with classes like `SpatialPoints` are likely to start failing in new and mysterious ways from now on... Check out Geocomputation in R for the modern way. https://r.geocompx.org/